# Dependency issue while installing fake86 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install fake86 on my laptop, in order to be able to write and run 8086 assembly programs. It fails to install because of a dependecy issue. It needs a package called `libsdl1.2debian-all`. So I wrote `sudo apt install libsdl1.2debian-all` which outputs

`This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the following packages replace it: libsdl1.2debian:i386 libsdl1.2debian`

`E: Package 'libsdl1.2debian-all' has no installation candidate`

Then, I tried to find package `libsdl1.2debian-all` from the web, but was unable to find a working link.

So, my question is, is it possible to install this program on my AMD64 Ubuntu 20.04 system?
Are there other alternatives for running 8086 assembly code on my computer?

By the way, I tried to compiling `i8086emu` with no success.

Comment: Try `libsdl1.2debian` instead.  Where did you get the fake86 package from?  Compiling it from hand is probably the best choice if it isn't already packaged.  If you like, I can try and walk you through that.